# How to filter on multiple columns with full text search

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a person table with the columns firstname, lastname, city and streetadress and a web gui where the user can search in the table.

Let's say the table contains 4 rows like:

```
Eva, Andersson, Stockholm, Kungsgatan 3
Adam, Johansson, Kiruna, Malmgatan 33a
Eva, Berquist, Kiruna, Gruvgatan 22
Adam, Stenberg, Kiruna, Lappfogdegatan 2
```

If the user searches for Eva Andersson Stockholm he/she shold only get a hit on "Eva, Andersson, Stockholm, Kungsgatan 3" and not on "Eva, Berquist, Kiruna, Gruvgatan 22". But a search on Adam Kiruna or just Eva should return two hits each.

Right now procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPersons]
@Search nvarchar(50) 

AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @SearchString varchar(100)

  SET @SearchString = REPLACE(@Search, ' ', '*" OR "')
  SET @SearchString = '"'+@SearchString+'*"'

  SELECT * FROM patients as p
  WHERE CONTAINS((Firstname, LasnName, City, Streetadress), @SearchString)
END
```

But it returns all rows containing any of the word so for the search "Eva Berquist Kiruna" it will return all four rows.

How should I write the procedure to get a correct result as described above?

Answer (score 0):

This would me my answer, please bare in mind that you need to do some procedural processes before querying the server. Here

```
Select * from Persons_Table where first_name = Eva AND Last_name = ....
```

Something like that.

Comment: The problem is that I don't now how many blank space seperated terms the search string contains or the order of them. It could be for example be "Firstname City" or "City Lastname Firstname". So I don't see how to do it with a plain where clause. Please elaborate you're example if you think it's possible to accomplish it this way.

Comment: Well, you need to filter that out before inserting that data into your table. Or you're gonna need a really complicated logic within an sql query.

Comment: The data are seperated in seperate columns but the search parameter aren't. Was that what you meant or did you mean the search parameter. It's imposible to filter it, for example the search Charles Lindberg shouldmreturn both Charles in the village Lindberg or Charles Lindberg who flew over the Atlantic Sea. That is if they exists in the DB of course.